# android studio error on startup (failed to create a child event loop)

Tags: android

I've seen this question like 10 times with no good answer. here's the problem whenever i open android studio this error comes up:

```
Internal Error. Please report to https://https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:81)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:48)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:57)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:67)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:54)
    at org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer.start(BuiltInServer.java:79)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock$2.call(SocketLock.java:133)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock$2.call(SocketLock.java:113)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.underLocks(SocketLock.java:157)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:113)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lockSystemFolders(StartupUtil.java:263)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:101)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:91)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:127)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:97)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:31)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:77)
    ... 18 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:68)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:170)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:125)
    ... 22 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:130)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:83)
    ... 30 more
```

now i've tried everything only "netsh winsock reset" works BUT for only one time and when i go inside Studio it can't build a project because it can't connect to the server using 127.0.0.1 .
please give a decent answer (NOT REINSTALL & RESTART.DONE THAT LIKE 20 TIMES)

The main issue is that even when i'm in android studio and i want to sync a project this error keeps popping up :

```
Error:Could not connect to server [7c2499c6-5abf-40a5-bcbb-1171adbb7e58 port:50376, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]]. Tried addresses: [/127.0.0.1].
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the approach in the second comment?https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206352

Comment: yes. as the third guy says both answers don't work. the second one DOES work but only for once. and it doesn't build the project , so technically useless.

Comment: I don't think it's useless, the problem must lie somewhere around there.